# Как сделать фон панели вкладок прозрачным?

Tags: c++, qt

Имеется `Qt::FramelessWindowHint`-окно. Каким образом можно сделать фон на панели вкладок(см. выделенное желтым на скрине) прозрачным, чтобы было красиво? То есть, чтобы всё осталось как было, только область, выделенная желтым стала прозрачной.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Такое уже спрашивали на SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688750/qwidget-transparent-background-but-not-the-children)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);`

```
#include <QTableWidget>
class Widget : public QTabWidget{
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0):
        QTabWidget(parent)
    {
        setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
        addTab(new QWidget(this), "Tab");
    }
};
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: А как можно вернуть всё как было после установки этих флагов? Пробовал писать `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, false); setWindowFlags(Qt::Widget);`, но фон становится черным.

Comment: @LNK, в справке написано: _Indicates that the widget should have a translucent background, i.e., any non-opaque regions of the widgets will be translucent because the widget will have an alpha channel. **Setting this flag causes WA_NoSystemBackground to be set**. On Windows the widget also needs the Qt::FramelessWindowHint window flag to be set. This flag is set or cleared by the widget's author._ Попробуйте `setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground, false);`

Comment: Да, если его отключить всё работает. спасибо.